# How to Measure HTML Page Dimensions

Tags: qt, html, dimensions

Let me simplify the question to this much.

-> I have a HTML file.(locally or remotely accessible)

-> I want to find the dimension of the web Page, that will generate if rendered

-> I cannot render it any way. I want to use it for tools like CutyCapt for image capturing and resizing.

thanks

Comment: The dimensions of many pages **vary** depending on window width … and font size … and various other factors.

Answer (score 1):

A page can be made to render a fixed size and/or some percentage of the browser window, therefore I don't think the question can be answered without some additional constraints or assumptions...

Answer (score 0):

Well, using JavaScript you can check the width & height of web-browser/webpage.

And if you want your images or text to be rendered according to browser width & height then you should define all width & height parameters of your text & image in percentage.